# javascript pick random line from a textarea

Tags: javascript, random, input, textarea, line

I'm trying to get a javascript pick a random line from a textarea. Sorry, big noob here.

Currently my code looks like this, and I'm quite sure there are silly mistakes in it. I'm just kinda stuck. First, how do I connect this function to the textarea? Secondly, how do I even output the result?
I think I've done too much there with making it two functions. I don't mind making it smaller somehow.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>
    Enter all of the names on a seperate line. <br />
</h3>
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter names here..."></textarea>   
</div>
<h3>The winner is: <span id = "winner"></span></h3>
<button onclick="randomSelect()">Click me</button>

<script>
function randomSelect() {
    
const lines = input.split('\n');
const randomLine = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length))];

selectOutput();}
}
function selectOutput() {
document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = ;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes should look like bellow:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <h3>
  Enter all of the names on a seperate line. <br />
 </h3>
 <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter names here..."></textarea>   
</div>
<h3>The winner is: <span id = "winner"></span></h3>
<button onclick="randonSelect()">Click me</button>

<script>
 function randonSelect() {
    const input = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    const lines = input.split('\n');
    const randomLine = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)];
    
    //Display your line
    document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = randomLine;
 }
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

You just forgotten to get the element from which you are getting the value.
But you did well.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot! (:

Answer (score 1):

```js
function randomSelect() {
  const winnerEl = document.getElementById("winner");
  winnerEl.innerHTML = "";
  const candidates = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
  if (candidates) {
    const names = candidates.split(/\n/);
    if (names.length > 0) {
      const max = names.length - 1;
      const winnerIndex = getRandomInt(0, max);
      winnerEl.innerHTML = names[winnerIndex];
    }
  }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>
    Enter all of the names on a seperate line. <br />
</h3>
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter names here..."></textarea>   
</div>
<h3>The winner is: <span id = "winner"></span></h3>
<button onclick="randomSelect()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `randomSelect()` function access your text area and value that is stored in it.
Thus add the following line

```js
    const input = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
```